# PubSubHubbub on ZeroMQ

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, real-time, zeromq, websub

Is it possible write a [PubSubHubBub](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/wiki/Hubs) hub service over [ZeroMQ](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall) ?

UPDATE:
I didn't intend rewrite PubSubHubbub protocol. I thought it was possible to write a HUB, implemented on top of ZMQ_PUB/ZMQ_SUB socket (zmq_socket(3)), but it's not clear to me until now, if it make sense or what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PubSubHubbub has its own protocol. To make 0mq use the protocol you would have to add a new teansport to 0MQ. Which is a rather complex thing to do, especially as PubSubHubbub protocol is based on XML and thus not that easily parsable.

You can implement PubSubHubbub/0MQ bridge though. It should be easy.

Comment: what's a bridge & does make it sense ? ... some exmple code ? ... ruby ?

Comment: Bridge is an application that takes data in one format and moves them on in another format. In this case from PubSubHubbub to 0MQ and vice versa.